# PhpStorm - extend PHP Class template

Tags: phpstorm

I'm trying PhpStorm. I like the `File Templates` functionality and I'd like to use it in some more specific cases.

I'd like to extend to `PHP Class` template to create a new template that I'll be using for a specific type of classes. If I just duplicate the template, it doesn't really work as I'd expect. For example, while when I use `PHP Class`, the namespace is already compiled, this does not happen with my new template.

Is it possible to create another template so that it works as `PHP Class`?

Moreover... is there a way to order the templates in the editor, so I could have my new template near all the other PHP templates?

Comment: 1) No -- only that predefined file template uses Dialog box; all other (custom) file templates will be ordinary File Templates with no extras; you might be interested in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-21711  2) No sorting  -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-75239

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne, you're comment could really become an answer

Comment: You can write some if statemens inside phpclass template. For example: if namespace is specific then you can extend class, add properties and etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to create another template so that it works as PHP Class?

Unfortunately not; at least not in current versions (2016.2).

When you are using `New | PHP Class` you see special dialog box that works with 3 templates (depends on what you will be creating: Class, Interface or Trait). This dialog uses file templates with predefined (default) names only and you can customize them as you wish .. but all other file templates for `.php` files will be just ordinary File Templates without those extras.

Based on your requirements you might be interested in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-21711 ticket -- watch it (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

**Please note** that file templates could be project-specific (different template content for each project) -- this might be enough in some (rather simple) cases.

---

> Moreover... is there a way to order the templates in the editor, so I could have my new template near all the other PHP templates?

Unfortunately not -- no sorting/subfolders is available (although you may have project-specific file templates).

Right now I may only suggest to use some common prefix in template name and build your sorting order around this idea.

Other than that -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-75239 + https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-3599 -- watch these tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.